# Why doesnt my output have () around repeating numbers and why doesnt it work?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
package dice.project;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class DiceProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your number of rolls:");
        int count = in.nextInt();
        int[]rollDice = new int[count];
        Random values = new Random();

        for(int m=0; m<count; m++)
        {
            rollDice[m]=values.nextInt(6)+1;
        }
        boolean inRun=false;
        for(int m=0; m<rollDice.length; m++)
        {
            if(inRun)
            {
                if(m>0 && rollDice[m]!=rollDice[m-1])
                {
                    System.out.print(")" + rollDice[m]);
                    inRun=false;
                }
            }
            if(!inRun)
            {
                if(m<rollDice.length-1 && rollDice[m]==rollDice[m-1])
                {
                    System.out.print("(" + rollDice[m]);
                    inRun=true;
                }
            }
            System.out.print(rollDice[m]);


         }
            if(inRun)
                System.out.print("(");

                    }
                }
```

Whats wrong with my program?
   When I run it i get an exception thing and it won't work?

```
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2166)        
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at dice.project.DiceProject.main(DiceProject.java:20)
```

This is also what shows up when i try the output?

Comment: What kind of Exception do you get? Can you edit in the whole block of code with the at java.util.... stuff?

Answer (score 1):

In your very first iteration of the second loop you are getting an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` thats because in that first iteration on this line:

```
if(!inRun){
    if (m < rollDice.length - 1 && rollDice[m] == rollDice[m - 1]) {
```

The variable `m` is 0 at this point and your are trying to get an index that doesnt exist in your array `rollDice[m - 1]` which will be -1. Fix that and you will see your program running. Maybe you will need to change your logic a bit.

Also try to use an IDE that allows you to debug your application.

Answer (score 0):

With given code getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception, however after changing for loops it works. I am not sure is that what you want :)

**What I did**

Changing your for loop variable `m` from `0` to `1` . It is working fine I guess.

```
for(int m=1; m<rollDice.length; m++) {
 ....
}
```

As I tested , for given input 12, I got output as  `52562434(44)556`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: ArrayIndexOutOfBounds]

Snapshot from eclipse debugger. Clearly, boundary conditions are not checked. When `m=0` array element for index `m-1` is being looked up which causes `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`in first iteration itself.